# How to get an image to gain an opacity as the page is scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I came across a cool feature I saw on a site. When you scroll down the main image on the page gains a dark opacity. I know how to add opacity, but specifically how do I add the opacity with the scroll?

http://designgroup.us.com/?utm_source=skycatchfire

Comment: OP should include things tried.

Comment: use $(document).scroll() function

Comment: @guradio I'm not looking for someone to create or give me code. I have no idea what I would do to even get this. Would it be something that I could create with waypoints?

Comment: Yes. Waypoints or a viewport library such as https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport

Comment: opacity is an adjective. you don't add **an** opacity, you just add opacity.

Comment: also, your example is manipulating brightness, not opacity.

Comment: @Pamblam How would I manipulate brightness?

Comment: also also, it's done with canvas. it's too much to write you an example but that should give you enough to google.

Comment: canvas could be an overkill.

Comment: @Pamblam I don't think it is done with brightness , its just an overlay with opacity

Comment: So brightness with a filter like this... `filter: brightness( 75%);` or something along those lines?

Comment: @Giri - *an* overkill... haha did you do that intentionally... but yes I suppose you could do it with CSS..

Comment: If you want brightness ye. But the example shown there in the link doesn;t use css filter or brightness. all you have to do is, img has opacity:1 and its parent div has background: black. when you change img's opacity:0.7; you get that effect. Use css transitions to get it animated

Comment: @pamblam yep. intentional

Comment: @Giri Thank you for the help so far. I know how to set the opacity with the black overlay, I just don't know how to progressively add it with a scroll funtion.

Comment: thing is, in order to do it on scroll you would have to dynamically create and change a `<style>` block in the DOM, which leads me to believe a canvas is used.

Comment: @Becky How about this https://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/av5h7L6f/ ?

Comment: Yes. That fiddle has image as background. Don;t need to be background. but again thats your preference. It just depends on the scenario

Comment: @Akshay Yes, that is definitely close to what I am after! Is there anyway to give it a limit of how much opacity is given rather than the full 100% and then just like in the link I added for it to go to that point at about the half way point. The reason I am after that is because the image I have is about 100% height of the page.

Comment: you have to use before and after selectors for that to work, which can't be manipulated directly thru javascript. you have to actually add teh style to the dom manually. i  wrote an article about it not too long ago: http://blog.geneticcoder.com/2015/12/09/rotate-and-cross-fade-background-images-with-jquery-css-background-opacity-trick/

Comment: @Pamblam Bushinator?

Comment: @Becky Use an `if` condition

Comment: idk what browesr you guys are on but that fiddle didn't do a thing in my browser. i don;t think that's going to work in all browsers. check out the source for my little plugin to get some ideas.

Comment: @Becky why dont you add a fiddle with a snippet of your html and css, we might be able to write the code. easier that way.

Comment: This is all I have now. I was trying to figure out how to get the overlay with my current structure, but wanted to get this posted in the mean time. https://jsfiddle.net/v5chxhwn/

Comment: @Becky here you go https://jsfiddle.net/v5chxhwn/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="home-main-img">
    <img src="http:optimumwebdesigns.com/images/demolition1.jpg" alt="Demolition and Wrecking" id="demolition1">
</div>

<div class="height">
</div>


#home-main-img img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
}

#home-main-img {
  background: #000;
}

.height {
  height:500px;
}

var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
var docHeight = $(document).height();
var diff = docHeight - scrollPosition;
console.log(scrollPosition);
$('#demolition1').css({'opacity':diff/docHeight});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v5chxhwn/2/

Comment: What does the height class of 500px do?

Comment: I added that so i could get the jsfiddle window to scroll. Document height more than the window height enables scrollbar.

Comment: Looks pretty good. I have two questions. Is there anyway to make it progressively add the opacity? Also I have a header above this and for some reason whenever it goes past the header, the header shows in some sort of opacity?

Comment: @Becky The jsfiddle is progressively removing opacity, you just need to reverse that. it would depend on what scenario, you must be able to come up with a logic.  header shows opacity? I'm not sure if i understand you right there

Comment: You can kind of see the header issue here: Scroll down some and you will see the header looks like it has some opacity effect. It never had that until now. https://jsfiddle.net/v5chxhwn/3/

Comment: @Becky add z-index to your header,   z-index:100;

Comment: Thanks. How do I control how much opacity is given? I don't really understand how to do that or the progression. Then how to get rid of that black gap at the bottom. Sorry for all the questions. I just want to fully understand this.

Comment: @Becky add 'display:block' into '#home-main-img img' to get rid of the black gap. This line 'diff/docHeight' needs to have your control logic. Its upto you how you want to calculate it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to figure it out. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Becky ok. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just give a div with the following styles and use the jquery scroll function to increase the opacity

```
.black-out {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1800px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Use the following jquery code

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
   var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (currentScroll > previousScroll){
       //Increase opacity using .css()
   } else {
      //Decrease opacity using .css()
   }
    previousScroll = currentScroll;
});
```